# Okta Single Sign On for SharePoint 2013 - how to inject custom claims from database

Tags: c#, sharepoint, single-sign-on, claims-based-identity, okta

**Scenario:**

We are using Okta Single Sign On (SSO) on a SharePoint 2013 Extranet facing site. It fits the requirement well when individual users(email as user identity) granted site permissions.

However, as part of claims based permissions, we have a need to append custom claims to the user identity based on a membership rank in a committee. The membership and rank information is stored in a SQL database.

Part of SSO installs, Okta provided a people picker (SPClaimsProvider). If I use the Okta people picker I have no control over to inject custom claims through SPClaimsProvider. They should dynamically injected by querying ranks from SQL database/CRM.

**Questions:**

Should we uninstall Okta people picker and **write** our own SPClaimsProvider to append custom claims (SPClaimsProvider)?

(OR)

Use Okta people picker and develop custom System.Security.Claims.ClaimsAuthenticationManager to inject claims

(OR)

Leave Okta people picker as is, write a new SPClaimsProvider and install in parallel to Okta people picker.

Looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last option works fine.  You can create and install multiple custom claims providers; the only limitation is that you can only have one default custom claims provider per SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer.  Just create a new custom claims provider and have it only inject claims by overriding the FillClaimsForEntity method.  Specific details for doing so are here (NOTE: this article works for both SharePoint 2010 and 2013): https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/writing-a-custom-claims-provider-for-sharepoint-2010-part-1-claims-augmentation-and-registering-your-provider/.